# How to access GPIO/SPI/I2C from NDK on Android (not Android Things)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-ndk, embedded, gpio

I'm doing some prototyping with Android on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Lineage OS (https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi3/LineageOS16.0/), which I think it's based on AOSP. Now I'm able to run a Hello Jni app with NDK. However, I need the access to GPIO/SPI/I2C interfaces from NDK to control sensors. The C libraries that I used for Raspberry Pi OS, wiringPi and PIGPIO, do not support Android out of the box.

I kinda understand how to access GPIO after watching this course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/internet-of-things-sensing-actuation/home/week/2. Based on my understanding, it's basically find the correct file for GPIO and change the value to control the interface.

However, even though I understand the concept that SPI is based on GPIO, but I couldn't figure out which file I need to access to control the interface, and how to deal with the 4-pin system for SPI instead of just interacting with 1 pin for GPIO.

As an Android or/and embedded dev newbie, I assume understanding how these interfaces work under the hood on Android would be helpful as well but I'm struggling to find documentation or code examples.

Any help on how GPIO/SPI/I2C works in Android, or how to enable them in RPi running Android is appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen: [Can I control GPIO Pins when using Android on the Pi 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/71857/26706) which in the comments links to: https://github.com/yang-neu/rpi3gpio which would create a Android API and appears to be a part of a custom ROM: https://github.com/yang-neu/pie-device-rpi3 **or** https://evmanic.com/monitoring-raspberry-pi-gpios-when-running-android/

Comment: Hi! Yeah I took a look at that. My understanding is that it requires me to build that specific version of AOSP myself and then flash to the RPi? Also, does it support SPI and I2C?

Comment: The first (github) project is an example for how to build your own hardware API, integration of SPI and I2C isn't there. For the second project link, the author is using LineageOS with root to run scripts, and sort-of interact with Android app. Accessing hardware GPIO/SPI/I2C is just putting bits in the right place, I believe as root, but Android's framework/permissions would block such access as a security/safety measure. Without knowing what you are trying to do, my advice is to understand GPIO on regular RPi Linux, perhaps try same in Android NDK, but may need Custom AOSP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I did a bit more research on the GPIO and SPI drivers and it seems that the Linage Kernel has the same interface as the RPi OS. So I was kinda ported WiringPi to work (still evaluating but basic GPIO APIs for C works, I think). What I was missing was to find the connection between the driver and the user space APIs.